# By design, why does the C# compiler allows any float or double values to be divided by zero?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

By design, why does the C# compiler allows any float or double values to be divided by zero?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x = 0.0 / 0;

        float y = 1f / 0;


    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: @John Saunders: `Console.WriteLine(1/0)` will cause a compiler error, while `Console.WriteLine(1.1/0)` will cause a runtime exception.

Comment: @David: There is no runtime exception in that case; the result is simply `double.PositiveInfinity`.

Comment: @John Saunders, an example has been added.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: indeed! my mistake entirely

Comment: Since you asked specifically for the default behavior I assume you know it; In case somebody does not: The `checked` keyword forces exceptions in case of overflows, divisions by zero, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because IEEE 754 floating-point values have special non-numeric values to deal with this:

```
PS Home:\> 1.0/0
Infinity
PS Home:\> 0.0/0
NaN
```

whereas dividing an integer by zero is always an exception (in the C# sense<sup>1</sup>), so you could just throw the exception directly.

---

<sup>1</sup> Dividing a floating-point number by zero is also an exception but at a completely different level and many programming languages abstract this away.

Comment: Btw. 1/0 == Infinity is mathematical nonsense.

Comment: @Luther: lim_(n->\infty) 1/n goes towards it, though. Of course, it's not an actual number in mathematics as well.

Comment: 1/x has a left and a right limit: `lim_(x->0+) 1/x = inf` but `lim_(x->0-) 1/x = -inf`. If the division behavior was defined using limits, then 0/0 should be 0 (not nan), because `lim_(x->0) 0/x = 0`. Never trust your FPU

Answer (score 1):

Because floating point values have a valid (and genuinely useful) representation of infinity, whereas integers of any type do not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the compiler allows you to divide a float or a double by zero, is that float and double have representations on the notion of positive infinity and negative infinity (and "not a number"), so it is a meaningful thing to allow.

One oddity is that the compiler fails spot

```
 decimal d = 2; 
 decimal d2 = d/0M
```

as a divide by zero, even though it does spot it if you write the equivalent code for an integer.

Comment: That's not true, division by zero on a `decimal` throws a `DivideByZeroException`, and the code `decimal d = 1.0M / 0.0M` will not even compile ("Division by constant 0").-.

Comment: @0xA3 - maybe, and yet decimal d = 2; decimal d2 = d/0M; does compile, even though the equivalent with integers does not.

Comment: @Rob Levine: My point was that your last paragraph doesn't make sense because division by zero is not a valid operation on the `decimal` type. It either does not compile or throws a runtime exception.

Comment: @Rob: That's likely an artifact of what the compiler optimizes immediately.

Comment: @0xA3 - I think maybe you misunderstood what I was saying in my last paragraph. Obviously it isn't actually a valid operation for a decimal - I'm not trying to suggest it is. My point was that given this fact, you might expect the compiler to not allow such an obvious case, as indeed it doesn't for an integer. To rephrase my last sentence: "Given the compiler can detect this invalid operation at *compile time* for an integer, it is perhaps suprising it doesn't do the same for the decimal"

Comment: @RobLevine: Compilers have code to optimize for division of non-constant integers by certain constant values.  Consequently, when generating code to divide a non-constant integer by a constant, the compiler will look to see what the constant is; if it's zero, the compiler will notice.  When using type `Decimal`, the compiler has code to deal with the case where the divisor and dividend are both constants, but not for the case where one is and the other isn't.